# Chrome Developer Tools console - inspect JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the old version of Chrome (not sure which version, I know it was quite some time ago), I could type the following into a console using the Chrome Developer Tools, and it would give me all associated properties of the newly created object:

```
document.createElement('a');
```

Now, when I do the same, I'm given very little back, and I can barely do anything with the returned item in the console, whereas I would just like to inspect it.

[image: chrome-dev-tools]

How do I view all the properties of this element, etc. as with the old version of Chrome - so I can inspect all properties and their values?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
console.dir(a)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason they took this behaviour out by default?

Comment: I don't think there's a changelog for the chrome devtools to look at, but I think it makes more sense - think about it, how would you "print" out the result of something by default? with `console.log` or `console.dir`?