# Where is a docs for Jupyter front-end extensions JavaScript API?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've read the [docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/frontend_extensions.html) about writing the Jupyter front-end extensions, and learn the [examples](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions), and now can build the simple extension by myself.

But - where is a complete docs for Jupyter extensions JavaScript API? How to find the JavaScript API for notebook properties and methods?

Answer (score 9):

This answer is **outdated**. Also see my answer below.

This might not be the answer you hoped for. However, it might help some readers being new to JavaScript development.

I also was looking for documentation on the Jupyter (-Notebook) client API and could not find official docs.

The JavaScript source code can be found on the GitHub repository, for example:

- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/859ae0ac60456c0e38b44f06852b8a24f8a1cfb0/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js
- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/4.2.2/notebook/static/services/kernels/kernel.js

What also helped was to

**A.** Use Google Chrome development tools, set a break point in the extension and type

```
Jupyter
```

in the console. Then you get a browsable tree structure that can be used to inspect the Jupyter object. That tree structure does not seem to contain methods.

**B.** Log all the properties of an object, including the methods. If you want to know about the methods of the notebook use for example

```
for(var property in Jupyter.notebook){ console.log(property)}
```

**C.** When typing in the console there is code completion. For example you might want to type

```
Jupyter.notebook.
```

and see the suggestions on how to complete the command:

[image]

Also see

- [How to inspect Javascript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357442/how-to-inspect-javascript-objects)
- [How to display all methods of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-of-an-object)
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24549/How-to-Inspect-a-JavaScript-Object
- [Chrome Developer Tools console - inspect JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811256/chrome-developer-tools-console-inspect-javascript-object)

Browsable tree structure in dev tools console:

[image]

How to list properties including methods:

[image]

...

[image]

Comment: And here is some example code in my project that uses the jupyter notebook: https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/treezjs/blob/master/src/jupyterTerminal.js

Comment: Updated links that demonstrate API usage:
**JupyterNotebook**: 
https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/treezjs/blob/master/jupyter_notebook_extension/jupyterTerminal.js
**JupyterLab**: 
https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/treezjs/blob/master/jupyter_lab_extension/jupyterLabTerminal.js

Comment: I'm not able to access the `Jupyter` variable in Javascript (either in Chrome's console or  using ipythons `%%javascript` tag). Any pointers how to get access to it ?

Thanks!

Comment: This old answer was related to JupyterNotebook and I guess you use JupyterLab?

Answer (score 3):

For newcomers it might be **confusing** that there are **several projects** with **similar names** for historical reasons:

a) **Jupyter**
https://github.com/jupyter

b) **JupyterLab**
https://github.com/jupyterlab/

c) The official **webpage**
https://jupyter.org/ 
references the newer b). 
However, the sub projects of a) **do not include deprecation warnings**.

=> If you find some documentation via search engine, you have to be careful if its related to a) or b).

**Current documentation** for **JupyterLab extensions** can be found here:

- General info:
  https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/user/extensions.html
- **Javascript API** doc:
  https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/modules.html
- Examples:
  https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples
- Discussion forum:
  https://discourse.jupyter.org/c/jupyterlab/extensions/

**Related**:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-JupyterLab-and-Jupyter-Notebook-Is-there-a-use-case-for-one-over-the-other?share=1

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-plugin-playground

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there are is no front-end API documentation, as there is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4897) that even references your SO question. Maybe a few +1s on the issue might change this, although I suspect that the answer (if any) will point to JupyterLab, which has a defined [front-end API](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/) but has no common technical base with Jupyter Notebook front-end extensions.